# Tratar dados de retorno da dataTable

Tags: jquery, jquery-datatables

Meu problema:

Preciso enviar um objeto a minha action. O componente que faz a gestão da tabelas hoje, adotado aqui na empresa, é a dataTable.

Pra eu enviar esse parâmetro, tive que alterar a forma de envio de:

```
"fnServerParams": function (aoData) { return aoData; },
```

Para:

```
"fnServerData": function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback, oSettings) {
                filterDataTable(sSource, aoData, fnCallback, oSettings);
},
```

O que acontece: na primeira requisição, onde não existe nenhum filtro, a tabela é carregada certinha. Entretanto, executando após a renderização qualquer filtro, ou paginação ou alteração da quantidade de registros na tabela ela não atualiza mais seus registros.

Implementando a função de callback é possível visualizar o retorno dos dados corretos mas como faço pra atualizar esse layout com os novos registros?

Se utilizar o `fnDraw` uma nova requisição será encaminhada ao servidor, já que a tabela tem configuração: `"bServerSide": true,`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A resolução do problema:

Meu objeto de filtro, recebido pela action é:

```
public Class Filter(){
       public ObjModel objModel {get; set;}
       public ObjDataTable objDataTable {get; set;}
    }
```

Assim, pensei que precisasse sobrescrever a forma de envio padrão dos parâmetros de busca, já que o parametro: `fnServerParams` só permite: chave/valor.

Alterei para o parametro, citado no post: `fnServerData`, que passou a renderizar a tabela com as infos corretas, entretanto, em qualquer interação (filtros, páginas, qntidade de registros), efetuava a requisição e obtinha o retorno certinho, mas, não fazia o reDraw da tabela.

Para resolver, voltei ao parametro: `fnServerParams` e adicionei os as chaves os prefixos dos objs:

```
"fnServerParams": function (aoData) {
                $.each(aoData, function (index, obj) {
                    obj.name = "filter." + obj.name;
                });

                $.each($(".meusElementos"), function (index, obj) {
                    aoData.push({ name: "model." + nomeDoelemento, value: valorDoelemento });
                });

                return aoData;
            }
```

A deserialização ocorre certinha para cada objeto e a tabela sempre é desenhada corretamente.